# Convert C++ for loop to python

Tags: python, c++, for-loop, while-loop

I am new to python. So, I converted C++ for loop to python. Please check if I have done it correctly. If not, then please inform me how to do it. If I am correct, then please inform me if there's any better and optimized way to do it.

C++ Code:

```
void printunorderedPairs(int[] array) {
    for (int i=0; i<array.length;i++){
        for (int j=i+1; j<array.length;j++){
            System.out.println(array[i] + "," + array[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

My Python Code:

```
i=0
while i<len(array):
     j=i+1
     while j<len(array):
         print(array[1],arr[2])
         j=j+1
     i=i+1
```

Comment: Your C++ looks like C#.

Comment: Shouldn't you actually use the values `i` and `j` in your Python code?

Comment: `print(array[1],arr[2])` should be `print(array[i],arr[j])`

Comment: FYI, in standard C++, arrays don't have methods associated with them.  Maybe you are programming in C# or C++/CLI?

Comment: Looks like Java to my eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python it's more idiomatic to use `for` loops, and you can use an array slice for the inner loop.

```
for i, el1 in enumerate(array):
    for el2 in array[i+1:]:
        print(el1, el2)
```